# How to make grep to stop searching in each file after N lines?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

It's best to describe the use by a hypothetical example:

Searching for some useful *header* info in a big collection of email storage (each email in a separate file). e.g. doing stats of top mail client apps used.

Normally if you do grep you can specify -m to stop at first match but let's say an email does not contact X-Mailer or whatever it is we are looking for in a header? It will scan through the whole email. Since most headers are <50 lines performance could be increased by telling grep to search only 50 lines on *any* file. I could not find a way to do that.

Comment: In this particular case, you may be better off with a more specific command like `reformail` to just extract the header(s) you want. See my more detailed [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64233383/111036) for a similar situation: extracting mail headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it would be faster but you could do this with awk:

```
 awk '/match me/{print;exit}FNR>50{exit}' *.mail
```

will print the first line matching `match me` if it appears in the first 50 lines. (If you wanted to print the filename as well, grep style, change `print;` to `print FILENAME ":" $0;`)

`awk` doesn't have any equivalent to `grep`'s `-r` flag, but if you need to recursively scan directories, you can use `find` with `-exec`:

```
find /base/dir -iname '*.mail' \
     -exec awk '/match me/{print FILENAME ":" $0;exit}FNR>50{exit}' {} +
```

You could solve this problem by piping `head -n50` through `grep` but that would undoubtedly be slower since you'd have to start two new processes (one `head` and one `grep`) for each file. You could do it with just one `head` and one `grep` but then you'd lose the ability to stop matching a file as soon as you find the magic line, and it would be awkward to label the lines with the filename.

Comment: so far it seems like the most elegant solution. is there a way to make it go recursively through dirs?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
head -50 <mailfile>| grep <your keyword>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it works only on one file or group of files on fixed number of dir depth. If I want to recursively search for files and grep I would need to add `find` in front and use xargs to pass to `head`. I would also lose filenames or path to file(s) with your solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
for i in *
do
    head -n 50 $i | grep -H --label=$i pattern
done
```

#### output:

```
1.txt: aaaaaaaa pattern aaaaaaaa
2.txt: bbbb pattern bbbbb
```

Comment: Hi kev. What does the sed part do and are you sure it will output file names?

Comment: @kev Why using `sed`? `grep -H` can print the filename with matched line.

Comment: @JS웃: But grep doesn't know the filename; only head knows and it's not telling. You could use `grep "--label=$i"`, though.

Comment: @rici Sorry didn't see it that way. My bad. Thanks for the explanation though. :)

Comment: Number of processes spawned = (2 * n) and OP said: `big collection of email storage (each email in a separate file)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.txt | xargs head -<N lines>| grep 'your_string'
```

Comment: Why not `head -n10 *.txt`. Also, your solution will probably fail on files with spacenames.

Comment: indeed problem with spaces in names