# How to extract email headers extending on multiple lines from file

Tags: linux, email, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to extract the To header from an email file using sed on linux.

The problem is that the To header could be on multiple lines.

e.g:

```
To: name1@mydomain.org, name2@mydomain.org,
    name3@mydomain.org, name4@mydomain.org, 
    name5@mydomain.org
Message-ID: <46608700.369886.1549009227948@domain.org>
```

I tried the following:

```
sed -n -e '/^[Tt]o: / { N; p; }' _message_file_ |
    awk '{$1=$1;printf("%s ",$0)};NR%2==0{print ""}'
```

The sed command extracts the line starting with To and next line.
I pipe the output to awk to put everything on a single line.

The full command outputs in one line:

```
To: name1@mydomain.org, name2@mydomain.org, name3@mydomain.org, name4@mydomain.org
```

I don't know how to keep going and test if the next line starts with whitespace and add it to the result.

What I want is all the addresses

```
To: name1@mydomain.org, name2@mydomain.org, name3@mydomain.org, name4@mydomain.org, name5@mydomain.org
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857424/extract-lines-between-2-tokens-in-a-text-file-using-bash

Comment: You really need to use procmail/formail for this. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/procmail.htm and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/formail.htm

Comment: @EdMorton: yes thank you. I did it like this:
cat _message_2 | formail -X To: | awk '{$1=$1;printf("%s ",$0)};NR%2==0{print ""}'

Answer (score 4):

`formail` is a good solution but here's how to do it with sed:

```
sed -e '/^$/q;/^To:/!d;n;:c;/^\s/!d;n;bc' message_file
```

- `/^$/q;` - (optional) quit if we run out of headers
- `/^To:/!d;` - if not a To: header, stop processing this line
- `n;` - otherwise, implicitly print it, and load next line
- `:c;` - c is a label we can branch to
- `/^\s/!d;` - if not a contination, stop processing this line
- `n;` - otherwise, implicitly print it, and load next line
- `bc` - branch back to label c (ie. loop)

Comment: Yes, it works if we just add a small ^ in front of the To otherwise it will print the first line containing To in the file. The command is now:

sed -e '/^$/q;/^To:/!d;n;:c;/^\s/!d;n;bc' _message_file

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Of course there should have been a `^` (it was in the comment!).

Comment: Just one little thing. The command adds an extra space in the end. 

But the simplest solution I could find is : formail -X To: < _message_2

Comment: The command proposed by @potong 
sed '/^\S/h;G;/^To:/MP;d' file just does the job in few actions

Answer (score 3):

Both `formail` and `reformail` have a `-c` option to do exactly that.

From `man reformail`:

> ```
> -c   Concatenate multi-line headers. Headers split on multiple lines
>      are combined into a single line.
> ```

So you don't need to pipe the output to awk, and can just do

```
reformail -c -X To: < $your_message_file
```

However, emails normally use CRLF line endings, and the output on screen may be garbled because of the CR characters. To remove them, you can use Perl's generic `\R` line ending in a regex on the output :

```
reformail -c -X To: < $your_message_file | perl -pe 's/\R/\n/g'
```

or do it on the input if you prefer:

```
perl -pe 's/\R/\n/g' $your_message_file | reformail -c -X To:
```

On Debian and derived systems like Ubuntu, you can install them with

- `apt install maildrop` for [reformail](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/reformail.html), which is part of [Courier's maildrop](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/)
- or `apt install procmail` for `formail` (but procmail seems to be abandoned now).

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this:

```
cat _message_file | formail -X To: | awk '{$1=$1;printf("%s ",$0)};NR%2==0{print ""}'
```

Or:

```
formail -X To: < _message_file | awk '{$1=$1;printf("%s ",$0)};NR%2==0{print ""}'
```

Comment: That's a [useless use of `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: Yes you are right. We can do like this:

formail -X To: < message_file | awk '{$1=$1;printf("%s ",$0)};NR%2==0{print ""}'

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^To:/{:a;N;/^ /Ms/\s*\n\s*/ /;ta;P}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the `-n` option. Gather up the lines starting with white space, removing white space either side of the newline and replace it by a single space, starting from the line that begins `To:`. When matching fails, print the first line in the pattern space.

To print addresses as is, use:

```
sed '/^\S/h;G;/^To:/MP;d' file
```

Comment: The second command worked! The first just prints the first line. Thank you

Comment: Okay, that second one is a bit mindbending :) I guess it's mostly portable (though not as short!) if written as: `sed '/^[^ ^T]/h;G;/\nTo:/P;d' file` where `^T` is a literal tab character

Answer (score 0):

It could be as straightforward as this:

```
sed -n '/^To:/{
    :a
    p
    n
    /^[[:space:]]/ba
}'
```

Be silent, but starting from the `To:` header print the text line by line while it still relevant to the header.